# Exception Tracing Within Task

Tags: c#

I'm having a hard time tracing an exception within a `Task`. The message returned from the exception isn't helpful at all. Below is the method that appears to be throwing the exception:

```
 public async Task<bool> TestProxy(IPEndPoint proxy)
 {
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(proxy.Address);

    if (reply == null || reply.Status != IPStatus.Success) return false;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    try
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

And here is the calling code:

```
public async Task<List<IPEndPoint>> FetchWorkingProxiesAsync()
{
    List<IPEndPoint> _proxies = await FetchRawProxiesAsync();
    List<IPEndPoint> workingProxies = new List<IPEndPoint>();

    Task[] tasks = new Task[_proxies.Count];

    for(int i = 0; i < _proxies.Count; i++)
    {
        IPEndPoint _tmpProxy = _proxies[i];

        tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {
                if (await TestProxy(_tmpProxy))
                {
                    workingProxies.Add(_tmpProxy);
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return workingProxies;
}
```

The exception that is being thrown is:

```
InnerException {"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."}   System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
```

When I set breakpoints no helpful information is available on the exception. I see that there's a `System.Net.WebException` but it doesn't say what or why.

I have CLR Throw and User Exceptions ticked in the Exceptions dialogue in VS.

**Edit**: I just realised I am not using the proxy to test the connection when attempting to connect to google.com. Even so, I'd still like to know how to find out more about the exception thrown.

Comment: Your `TestProxy` returns false before doing something with the Exception (the compiler should warn you about 'unreachable code'). Try switching those statements.

Comment: I see. But if that was the case no exception would be thrown anyway if it returned false as it'd never get to the HTTP request. From the exception message above it seems to be a `WebException` and not a `PingException`.

Comment: Do you still get a `System.Net.WebException` when you remove the try/catch block around `await TestProxy(...)` and just do the await?

Comment: Will test it in a moment and see.

Comment: @Stefan yes the error still occurs.

Comment: So the exception is still the same? Can you post the whole stack trace?